# Helm Chart: How do I install dependencies first?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I've been developing a prototype chart that depends on some [custom resource definitions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/api-extension/custom-resources/) that are defined in one of the child charts.

To be more specific, I'm trying to create the resources defined in the [strimzi-kafka-operator](https://strimzi.io/) within my helm chart and would like the dependency to be explicitly installed first. I followed the [helm documentation](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/chart_best_practices/dependencies/) and added the following to my Chart.yaml

```
dependencies:
- name: strimzi-kafka-operator
  version: 0.16.2
  repository: https://strimzi.io/charts/
```

I ran:

```sh
$ helm dep up ./prototype-chart
$ helm install ./prototype-chart
> Error: unable to build Kubernetes objects from release manifest: unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "KafkaTopic" in version "kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta1"
```

which shows that it's trying to deploy my chart *before* my dependency. What is the correct way to install dependencies first and then my parent chart?

(For reference, here is the question I opened on GitHub directly with Strimzi where they informed me they aren't sure how to use their helm as a dependency:
https://github.com/strimzi/strimzi-kafka-operator/issues/2552
)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Regarding CRD's: the fact that Helm by default won't manage those<sup>1</sup> is a feature, not a bug. It will still install them if not present; but it won't modify or delete existing CRD's. The previous version of Helm (v2) *does*, but (speaking from experience) that can get you into all sorts of trouble if you're not careful. Quoting from the link you referenced:

> There is not support at this time for upgrading or deleting CRDs using Helm. This was an explicit decision after much community discussion due to the danger for unintentional data loss. [...] One of the distinct disadvantages of the crd-install method used in Helm 2 was the inability to properly validate charts due to changing API availability (a CRD is actually adding another available API to your Kubernetes cluster). If a chart installed a CRD, helm no longer had a valid set of API versions to work against. [...] With the new crds method of CRD installation, we now ensure that Helm has completely valid information about the current state of the cluster.

The idea here is that Helm should operate only at the level of **release** data (adding/removing deployments, storage, etc.); but with CRD's, you're actually modifying an extension to the Kubernetes API itself, potentially inadvertently breaking other releases that use the same definitions. Consider if you're on a team that has a "library" of CRDs shared between several charts, and you want to uninstall one — formerly, With v2, Helm would happily let you modify or even delete those at will, with no checks on if/how they were used in other releases. **Changes to CRDs are changes to your control plane / core API**, and should be treated as such — you're modifying global resources.

In short: with v3, Helm positions itself more as a "developer" tool to define, template, and manage releases; CRDs, however, are meant to be managed independently e.g. by a "cluster administrator". At the end of the day, it's a win for all sides, since developers can setup/teardown deployments at will, with confidence that it's not going to break functionality elsewhere... and whoever's on call won't have to deal with alerts if/when you accidentally delete/modify a CRD and break things in production :)

---

See also the extensive discussion [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/pull/833) for more context behind this decision.

Hope this helps!